# Need to access variable from code behind. What i found shows how to go about it but i but the value keep displaying null

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

How to access and use javascript variables from code behind (C#). Upon research, i implemented the proccess in accessing the variables but i still do not get the values of the variables. Where am i going wrong?

```
 //Javascript
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function OnSucceeded() {            
        var status = 65;
        var state = "pass value"
        document.getElementById("getValue").value = status;
        document.getElementById("getvalues").value = state;
    }
</script>


//
  <asp:HiddenField ID="getValue" runat="server" Value="" />
  <asp:HiddenField ID="getvalues" runat="server" Value="" />

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="OnSucceeded()" Text="Button"
        OnClick="Button1_Click" />

 //C# code behind
  ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" +    getvalues.Value + "');", true);
```

Comment: Please describe in more detail what you are trying to achieve (what you're actually trying to do - *not* how you're trying to do it) and post all of the relevant code, as it is currently impossible to know what's going on.

Comment: Take a look at the [Passing javascript variables to server-side C# logic][1] post as it covers the same ground.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024651/passing-javascript-variables-to-server-side-c-sharp-logic

Comment: thank you all for the help. Khanh TO's solution made it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ClientID to render correct IDs of server controls

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnSucceeded() {            
        var status = 65;
        var state = "pass value"
        document.getElementById("<%= getValue.ClientID %>").value = status;
        document.getElementById("<%= getvalues.ClientID %>").value = state;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @ Khanh TO -Thanx alot. Using ClientID made it word. the value now shows. Thanx again