# how to call javascript function from code behind

Tags: javascript, c#-3.0

Javascript:

```
function ConfirmIt() {
    var x = confirm("Do you Want to Delete The Point ??");
    var control = '<%=inpHide.ClientID%>';
        if (x == true) {
            document.getElementById(control).value = "1";
        } else {
            document.getElementById(control).value = "0";
        }
}
```

Code behind:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "JsStatus", "ConfirmIt();", true);
int DiagResult = int.Parse(inpHide.Value);
if (DiagResult == 1)
{
    // db.delete_Geo_Routepoints(userid);
}
```

I want to be able to call JavaScript code from the backend only, but the code that I currently have isn't able to do so.  How am I supposed to get the value?

Comment: Impossible unless you use AJAX, and if you want to get it without cooperation with your client-side code that's completely impossible.  Possible duplicate of [Passing javascript variables to server-side C# logic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024651/passing-javascript-variables-to-server-side-c-sharp-logic)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is client-side code you cannot get output on Code behind